# How to get authenticated identity response from AWS Cognito using boto3

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-cognito

I would like to use boto3 to get temporary credentials for access AWS services. The use case is this: A user in my Cognito User Pool logs in to my server and I want the server code to provide that user with temporary credentials to access other AWS services.

I have a Cognito User Pool where my users are stored. I have a Cognito Identity Pool that does NOT allow unauthorized access, only access by users from the Cognito User Pool.

So here is the code I am starting with:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('cognito-identity','us-west-2')
resp = client.get_id(AccountId='<ACCNTID>',
                     IdentityPoolId='<IDPOOLID>')
```

However, just running these three lines of code throws an exception:

```
botocore.errorfactory.NotAuthorizedException: An error 
occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling 
the GetId operation: Unauthenticated access is not 
supported for this identity pool.
```

Since my Cognito Identity Pool is not set up for unauthenticated access, it seems that I cannot call get_id until I somehow authenticate somewhere.

How do I solve this? What exactly do I need to do to authenticate so I can call get_id?

UPDATE: Looks like I need to pass a Logins field and data to the get_id function call, but to do that I need the login JWT token. If I am running this inside a webapp (eg a Django backend) where I use the AWS Cognito prepackaged login screens, then yes I can get this from the homepage URL after redirection from successful login. But now I am writing some test scripts that have nothing to do with a website. Is there a way to use boto or boto3 or some other python package to login with username and password and get JWT token?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To pass the Cognito User Pool JWT Token, you would need to use the `Logins Map` in the `GetId` API call. You could try the following Python code out on your end, after replacing the necessary placeholders.

```
response = client.get_id(
    AccountId='string',
    IdentityPoolId='string',
    Logins={
        'cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>': '<JWT ID Token>'
    }
)
```

If you do not provide a Logins Map, Amazon Cognito treats the authentication event as Unauthenticated, and hence, you are facing this error.

Comment: Thanks but this begs the question: where do I get the JWT token? Is there a way to get this using boto or boto3?

Comment: You get the JWT Token after a successful User Pool authentication event.This can be attained using the InitiateAuth or the AdminInitiateAuth API calls.

Comment: You could refer to [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.initiate_auth) API.

Answer (score 9):

Just to add to the answer from Arka Mukherjee above, to get the token I do this:

```
auth_data = { 'USERNAME':username , 'PASSWORD':password }
provider_client=boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name=region)
resp = provider_client.admin_initiate_auth(UserPoolId=user_pool_id, AuthFlow='ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH', AuthParameters=auth_data, ClientId=client_id)
token = resp['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken']
```

Here I have to use the username and password of the Cognito user, client_id is the app client id for the app client that I set up thru Cognito, and user_pool_id is the user pool id.

Note that my app client has this option checked/selected: Enable sign-in API for server-based authentication (ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH) and I created that app client with no secret key (apparently that is important for web clients especially).